# What does it mean, "Medicine these days is all about covering your ass"?

Tags: meaning

Anesthesiologist meets Paul, occupational Therapist:

> Paul: Yeah, well, I get a little carpal tunnel of my own from time to
>   time.
>
> Anesthesiologist :Tell me about it. **Medicine these days is all about
>   covering your ass**.

What does it mean, "Medicine these days is all about covering your ass"?

Does it mean Medicine should talk the blame but not 
now these days?

I find these line in Downsizing 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the speaker of the phrase thinks that the practice of medicine often involves taking self-protective measures to guard against criticism or legal liability.

Here's a lot about the phrase:
[Wikipedia "cover your ass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass)